# Join two database tables and output resutls to HTML table

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

For my current progress I need to create a table like the one below

```
pid cid eid name value

1    1   4   name  ab
2    1   5   amt    2
3    1   4   name   cd
4    1   5   amt    4
```

Instead of creating the table like this

```
pid cid  name amt

1    1    ab    22
2    1     cd    4
```

Anyhow created table as my wish with the below code

```
<table width="1204" height="100" border="1">
  <tr>
  <?php  $sqlname="Select * From  elements  where cat_id='1' order by e_id ";   
           $resname=mysql_query($sqlname);
           while($rowname=mysql_fetch_array($resname)){

          ?>
    <td colspan="2"><?php echo $rowname['lable_name']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <?php $i=0; 
  $sqlprolist="select value from products_list where name='".$rowname['lable_name']."' and e_id='".$rowname['e_id']."'";
          $resprolist=mysql_query($sqlprolist);
          while($rowprolist=mysql_fetch_array($resprolist)){
              $i++;

         ?>
    <td><?php echo $rowprolist['value'];?></td>
    <?php if($i%8==0){
        ?>
        <tr></tr>
        <?php }?>
    <?php }?>
  </tr>
  <?php }?>
</table>
```

But I don't have any idea to retrieve data from the table for processing.

thanks

as by following martin the table created as like the below table

```
pid cid eid name  value

12   1  4  name    abc
1    1  4  name    cde
13   1  5  code    12
2    1  5  code    14
```

how to split up the data 
like

```
name code breeder quality size

abc   12   121     121     22
acfd  34   164     22      22
```

thanks

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: you can either add align="left" to your cell (`<td aling="left">`) or use div and css which i would suggest, this is basic html

Comment: @N.B. i guess he's asking about alignment

Comment: i like to store the data in database as in the above table thanks for all your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to help you without seeing database structure. Please share it with us, you might get better answers.

Anyway, I suppose you have two tables, `elements` and `products_list`. It looks like you need to lookup the `value` column in the `products_list` for every row in the `elements` table. You can merge these table into one result set using a single SQL query:

```sql
SELECT e.p_id, e.cat_id, e.e_id, e.lable_name, p.value
FROM elements e, products_list p
WHERE e.cat_id='1' AND 
p.name = e.lable_name AND p.e_id = e.e_id
ORDER BY by e.e_id
```

Note that the `e.p_id` is just a guess, you have not shared with us, where the "pid" column value gets from. Also not sure, if you actually need to match the rows using the `p.name = e.lable_name`. If `e_id` is primary key, you might do with `p.e_id = e.e_id` only.

What's the point of `cid` column? If it is indeed the `cat_id` column in database, why do you need it in HTML table, if you filter the elements to `cat_id=1` anyway? Was that intentional?

You can now take the results of the query and simply output it to a HTML table row by row like:

```php
<table width="1204" height="100" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>pid</th>
    <th>cid</th>
    <th>eid</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>value</th>
  </tr>
  <?php

    $sqlname =
        "SELECT e.p_id, e.cat_id, e.e_id, e.lable_name, p.value ".
        "FROM elements e, products_list p ".
        "WHERE e.cat_id='1' AND ".
        "p.name = e.lable_name AND p.e_id = e.e_id".
        "ORDER BY e.e_id";   
    $resname = mysql_query($sqlname);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resname))
    {
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['p_id'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['cat_id'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['e_id'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['lable_name']);?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['value'];?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php 
    }
  ?>
</table>
```

This is just a first step. It's unlikely this is correct answer. But I hope it helps you understand, what are you trying to do and to your question.

This is hardly production-grade code. But I wanted to do as little changes as possible, so you can see, what is the actual change from your code.

Also note that the `mysql_` functions are deprecated. See the big red box on [PHP documentation page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Comment: thanks @Martin my database is perfectly matched your query... but now how i can split the data as single row

Comment: What do you mean by "split the data"? What data? How do you want to split it? Why? What do you want to do with the results?

Comment: I understood that you want to merge (not split) the data from two tables into single HTML row. That's what my example shows.